# Quantity of hemoglobin in the cells

Tags: physiology

According to my book- red blood cells have the ability to concentrate hemoglobin in the cell fluid upto about 34g in each 100 ml of cells.The concentration does not rise above this value because this is the metabolic limit of cell's hemoglobin-forming mechanism.
Furthermore, In normal people,the percentage of hemoglobin is almost always near the maximum In each cell.
The next statement says- the quantity of hemoglobin in each respective cell contains an average of 15g of hemoglobin per 100ml.
So what is the actual concentration of hemoglobin in 100 ml of blood?

Comment: **Homework questions** are off-topic on Biology **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. For more information see our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).

Answer (score 2):

The reference range for **hemoglobin** *Hb* content in whole blood is 13 - 17 g/100ml for adult men, and 12 - 16 g/100ml for adult women.

There are other related metrics : the **mean corpuscular hemoglobin concentration** *MCHC*, that is the concentration in a red blood cell (reference range : 31 - 36 g/100mL), and **mean corpuscular hemoglobin** *MCH*, which is mass in one cell (reference range : 29 - 35 pg)

So I think that book is refering to different values :  the concentration in the red blood cell itself (*MCHC* = 34g/100ml), and the resulting concentration in the whole blood (*Hb* = 15g/100ml).

By the way, there is a value relating *Hb* and *MCHC*, the **hematocrit** *Ht*, the proportion of volume of whole blood occupied by red blood cells. Reference range 40% - 50% for adult men, 35% - 47% for adult women.